# Using jira api to get all version for a specified project

Tags: java, jira

I have the code below which is working with some projects from my Jira URL, but is not working with all the projects, and I have access for all of them. I don't understand why this code is not getting me the correct answer for all my projects.
When I try with a project that is not working, my response in JSON Format will be:

```
{
  "errorMessages": [
    "No project could be found with key 'CRAFTIDGDS'."
  ],
  "errors": {}
}
```

```java
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI uri = URI.create(JiraProperties.getInstance().getJiraUrl() + "rest/api/2/project/" + jiraProject.getProjectName() + "/versions");
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: For the project which is not working , can you try calling [Get Project](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/project-getProject) and check if it gets you any result.

Comment: @Rambler , if I'm calling get all Projects api , I m not getting that Project I can not parse , but if I m going to Jira I can see that Project and also Access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no authentication in the code sample that you provided so I guess you're retrieving info anonymously.

If you add basic authentication and use a user with appropriate permissions then you should get results.

Answer (score 1):

Like GlennV says there was no authentication in my code so I added it, and it's working just fine:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlRequest);
    httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(JiraProperties.getInstance().getJiraUsername(), JiraProperties.getInstance().getJiraPassword()),
            "UTF-8", false));

    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return   httpResponse.getEntity();
```